# Aligning comment date bottom right in a container

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

[image: Date alignment]

I am trying to align that grey date at the bottom right in that container.
It should float there at the base of the container and not at the end of the text.
I made a CodePen for it: http://codepen.io/adrianTNT/pen/IciCH

Any ideas? 
I can probably do it with a messy code but I am sure there must be a clean way to do it with the proper CSS code.

```
body{
    background-color:#0e91a1;
  padding:10px;
}

.comment{
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #555;
    min-height:50px;
}

.comment_text{
    font-family:monospace, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New";
}

.comment_date{
    font-family:monospace, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New";
    color:#CCC;
    display:inline-block;
    float:right;
}

img.comment_avatar{
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:5px;

}
.comment_name{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution: http://jsfiddle.net/7kdar/2/.

First, the `.comment` paragraph is positioned relatively:

```
.comment{
    padding:10px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #555;
    min-height:50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Second, the `.comment_date` is positioned absolutely using the `.comment` coordinates:

```
.comment_date{
    font-family:monospace, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", 
                "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New";
    color:#CCC;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Third, to make sure that the `.comment_date` does not overlap with the `.comment_text`, a new invisible element is appended to the end of `.comment_date` that is the size of the largest date:

```
.comment_text:after {
    content: "3 Jul 23:36";
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, but isn't it more accurate instead `.comment_text:after` to use `margin-right:80px;` on the `.comment_text` ? Seems to work on first tests, if you agree, then maybe you can adjust the answer.

Comment: Well, first, `span`s are inlines, therefore you cannot set `margin-right` on it.  `.comment_text` display can be changed to `inline-block` and then the `margin-right` can be set.  The effect is not that great: http://jsfiddle.net/7kdar/5/, because all of the text gets pushed to the left.  This is why I suggested appending a piece of invisible text using `:after`.  The latter method affects only the last line.

Comment: By the way, the `:after` piece of code was meant to implement the padding on the last line of the text and `content: "3 Jul 23:36";` is meant to create just enough space.  For production version, you may want to set the width on the `:after` element explicitly.  Here's a fiddle that sets the `:after` content as `inline-block` and widens it to 110px.  You may need to adjust that number to fit your purposes.  It's cleaner than using a date text.  http://jsfiddle.net/7kdar/6/.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `float: right;` for your `.comment_date` `span` like at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HpBGd

**EDIT:** Also remove `display:inline-block` and change the `<p>` to a `<div>` and the `comment_date` `<span>` to a div as I have done in the above codepen (updated) and I think it'll resolve the issues.

[image]

Comment: that alone doesn't do it, because it floats after the comment text and not at the bottom of that container.

Comment: In other words, if there is only one word of comment, then date/time element should still be in the bottom right corner.

Comment: @DRD exactly. So if there is just a very short text, then the date should NOT be on top, but at the bottom right.